# Rails 3.2 - Update Attributes at Create - I'm stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

trying to create an "award" record.  I have 2 selection boxes calling the Employee model to populate the Nominator and Nominee in the Award.

The Employee table gets dropped and recreated every night via a batch job, so I need to capture all the metadata attributes (first_name, last_name, etc) of the Nominator and Nominee at the time of award creation.

Normally, I would just have an employee_id foreign key in the award model, then call the employee attributes dynamically, but the employee data is dropped each night, so I'm totally stuck on the logic on how to do this.  Please help!  And thanks in advance!

```
class AwardsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @award = Award.new(params[:award])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @award.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_award_path, notice: 'Award was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @award, status: :created, location: @award }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @award.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
<%= form_for(@award) do |f| %>
  <% if @award.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@award.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this award from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @award.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %> 
<h4>I am...</h4>
  <label>Name</label>
    <%= f.collection_select :nominator_username, Employee.active.order(:last_name), :username, :lastfirst, :include_blank => true %>


<hr>
<h4>I would like to nominate...</h4>
    <label>Name</label>
    <%= f.collection_select :nominee_username, Employee.active.order(:last_name), :username, :lastfirst, :include_blank => true %>


    <h4>For providing the following...</h4>
    <%= f.text_area :award_description, :size => "50x7" %>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="spacer"></div><p>

<% end %>
```

-

```
class CreateAwards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :awards do |t|
        t.string    :nominator_first_name
        t.string    :nominator_last_name
        t.string    :nominator_username
        t.string    :nominator_phone
        t.string    :nominator_employee_number
        t.string    :nominator_mail_station
        t.string    :nominee_first_name
        t.string    :nominee_last_name
        t.string    :nominee_username
        t.string    :nominee_employee_number
        t.string    :nominee_phone
        t.string    :nominee_mail_station
        t.text      :award_description
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I created a rake task:

```
#\lib\tasks\import.rake
require 'csv'

desc "Import employees from csv file"
task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "db/users.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
    Employee.find_or_create_by_username({
      :username => row[0],
      :last_name => row[1],
      :first_name => row[2],
      :employee_number => row[3],
      :phone => row[4],
      :mail_station => row[5]
    }
    )
  end
end
```

When I run rake import.rake, I get:

```
*Don't know how to build task 'import.rake'*

/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE - Here is my final rake task.  I am getting an error with the final update_column block: *undefined method 'update_column' for nil:NilClass***

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import employees from csv file"
task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "db/users1.csv"

    to_be_deactivated = {}
        Employee.all.each do |e|
        to_be_deactivated[ e.employee_number ] = true
    end

  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
    e = Employee.find_or_create_by_employee_number( row[:employee_number] )

    to_be_deactivated[ e.employee_number ] = false

    e.update_attributes(
      :last_name => row[1],
      :first_name => row[2],
      :phone => row[4],
      :mail_station => row[5]) 

    e.save
    end

    to_be_deactivated.each do |n|
        e = Employee.find_by_employee_number( n )
        e.update_column(:active, false)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Rails application, and you're not just piggy-backing on a legacy database, then I would recommend to not drop and re-import the employee table entirely, but to run a Rails-based import job, which uses the accounting employee-number to match records, and then does a `find_or_create_by_employee_number` -- so your Rails ids stay the same throughout your app.

You can set-up Rails to access multiple databases, and you can then read from the accounting DB and match those records against the Rails app's DB.

If you can't get direct read access to the accounting DB, then use the nightly dump, to populate a temporary DB, which you access as a secondary DB in Rails, and then match the employee records with a script/runner or rake based script that you can start via cron or delayed job.

That is probably the cleaner way to deal with this.

Then you can just use the Rails id for the employees in your awards model.

Dropping the database table, and re-creating it every night is not a good idea, because all your references become useless.

---

If you don't like that suggestion, then you could use the internal accounting employee number as the unique identifier in the awards model. You don't need to store all the other attributes, because the employee number will not change for the same person -- just do a `find_by_employee_number`

---

```
 to_be_deleted = {} # empty Hash
 Employee.all.each do |e|
     to_be_deleted[ e.employee_number ] = true
 end

 # now run your rake task with LDAP import.
 CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
   e = Employee.find_or_create_by_employee_number( row[:employee_number] )

   to_be_deleted[ e.employee_number ] = false

   #... 
   e.update_attributes( ... )
   e.save
 end

 # any records which were not updated by the LDAP import
 # need to be deleted:

 to_be_deleted.each do |n|
    e = Employee.find_by_employee_number( n )
    e.destroy  # also deletes associated records; otherwise use delete
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not quite sure I understand.. I populate my Employee model from a daily LDAP .csv export of certain fields.  I think I do have to store all the employee attributes at the time of Award creation because the Employee table can change daily - hires/retires/name changes, etc, so a find_by later may not find anything, and historical award data would be lost.  Like you said, all my references would be useless.  I'm sorry, am I making sense or just missing the point?

Comment: LDAP, nice! I've done that in the past :) My point was that you don't have to create entirely new employee records every night! You can use Rails's `find_or_create_by_employee_number` to check if a previous record for that employee already exists, and then just update that record, instead of creating a new one every night. So only new employees would get a new records. Employees who left, will have to be dealt separately, depending on if your LDAP feed sends that info as well. If your LDAP feed contains retired employees then you can identify them (last_day_of_work) and delete the Rails record

Comment: If the LDAP feed does not carry retired employees, then you can add a field to your Rails employee model, and set it before the nightly import runs -- unset that field for every employee record which was sync'ed from LDAP -- after the nightly sync, any Rails employee records with that field set are to be deleted.

Comment: Ohhh, I think I understand now.  I was wondering how I could "append" the existing employee table without re-importing the same records over and over! That's how, huh?  I will look into that and let ya know - thanks!

Comment: you might also want to check-out the Gem `smarter_csv` to process the CSV file in batches / or in parallel

Comment: I updated my original post with an error I'm now getting.  I just saw your suggestion regarding smarter_csv and will look into that (hey! that's you! hehe).  Oh, and I checked your answer as correct.  Thanks

Comment: does it show up with `rake -T` ?  What does `rake -V` give you?

Comment: It mostly works now! I was using "rake import.rake" instead of just "rake import"  DUH.  It does not change attribute values if any change, and it does not remove values not found in the new CSV file.  I will open a new post for those issues, though.

Comment: btw - i would not recommend to do `find_or_create_by_username`, because if a person changes their name, it will not work. 
It's more reliable to do `find_or_create_by_employee_number`

Comment: I did that, thanks.  Not sure how to deactivate records in my table based on the LDAP dump not having the record anymore.  I only get active users in my dump file... I have an "active" boolean in my table that I can toggle if the record isn't found in the CSV file, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks - I'm almost there.  I am getting an error when attempting to set employee.active to false if the record is no longer found in the import file  (instead of deleting the employee record, I just want to deactivate it to retain all the historical data).  I updated my original post.